# How to initialize a list of integers from stdin reading each integer on a separate line in haskell?

Tags: list, haskell, integer, stdin

I am a newbie in Haskell but I know C++ and Java. now I wonder how can I read a list of integers similar to this psuedocode?

```
   cout << "Please enter the size of your list";
   cin >> list_size;
   int mylist[listsize];
   for (int i = 0 ; i<list_size; i++) {
      cout<< "please enter the next number:";
      cin>> number;
     mylist[i]=number;
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading input from stdin in haskell and converting to list of integers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20755395/reading-input-from-stdin-in-haskell-and-converting-to-list-of-integers)

Comment: This is not a possible duplicate at all, because the essay you are suggesting DOES NOT read the input while communicating with the user who submits the list members. there is a big difference between waiting for input with a printed prompt and reading the data in one push. Both solutions between this essay and yours are different.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The answers given in the linked question use lazy IO (through [`getContents`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:getContents)).

Personally, I don't like lazy IO, and I think trying to understand how it works in combination with do-notation is a recipe for confusion. So here's an answer that doesn't use lazy IO:

```
import Control.Monad(replicateM)

main :: IO ()
main = do
    putStrLn "Please enter the size of your list"
    times <- readLn
    ns <- replicateM times 
                     (do putStrLn "please enter the next number: "
                         readLn :: IO Int) -- type annotation to remove ambiguity
    print ns
```

[`replicateM`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:replicateM) takes a number *n* and an effectful action, and returns a new action that executes the original *n* times and returns a list with the results.

### What if I want to display a different prompt message for each number?

That can be understood as an effectful transformation on the list of prompt messages, one that substitutes each message by the value entered. A kind of "effectful map".

The function [`traverse`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Traversable.html#v:traverse) can be used here. Or perhaps [`for`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Traversable.html#v:for), which is the flipped version of `traverse`:

```
{-# language ScopedTypeVariables #-}

import Data.Traversable (for)

main :: IO ()
main = do
    putStrLn "Please enter the size of your list"
    times :: Int <- readLn
    ns <- for [1..times]
              (\prompt -> do putStrLn ("enter " ++ show prompt)
                             readLn :: IO Int) -- type annotation to remove ambiguity
    print ns
```

The `:: IO Int` annotation is required in the example because [`readLn`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:readLn) can read any type that has a `Read` instance, but we aren't doing anything Int-specific with the results, so we need to inform the compiler about the type somehow.

Comment: Thanks mate for your time. What I think about Haskell is that there should be some lessons about reading input in different ways. I rarely find them online.

Comment: @superlinux Hopefully the Documentation site will help with that.